# Get data from div class using selector and find

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the list of restaurants from this webpage, the type and the address. So far I wrote this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.takeout2unow.com/restaurants?collapsable=1'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '\
       'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '\
       'Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")


results = []

for restaurant in soup.select('.dd_bs a.dd_restlink'):
 results.append({
    'title':restaurant.find('div',{'class':'menu__vendor-name ng-binding'}).text,
    'address': restaurant.find('div',{'class':'vendor_details_item 
 vendor_details_address'}).text,
    'details': restaurant.find('div',{'class':'vendor_details_item ng- 
 binding'}).text,
    'type': restaurant.find('div',{'class':'servesCuisine'}).text
    
        })
results
```

Output

```
[]
```

I do not know if I am selecting the wrong item or why I cannot get any data

Answer (score 0):

This is simply because the data you are trying to scrape isn't gotten when the website is loaded. Only a shell of the website is returned by the get request you sent and contains the general things on the website.

The data is later gotten by sending a post request to "https://www.takeout2unow.com/left.json.xsl" which contains a JSON file with all the data.
NB: You can also use a get request with that link

It is important to tackle the most basic stages when writing scrapers, first of all confirm that you have data before trying to parse through it.